# Php Script to distribute person working in a week

Tags: php, html-table

I made this Script to distribute person working in a week but No one can work more than one time in a day and  also must work 6 days/week, but still some problems cause some people work just 4 days some work more.
Question : how to make people work 6 days per week?
...  I tried doing it this way:

```
<?php
$input = array("Mohamed ET Sidi",  "Ahmed ET ibrahim",  "senoud","Hamed Et abdou");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 4);
?>

<table  border=1>
    <tr>
        <th> Samedi </th> 
        <th> Dimanche </th> 
        <th> Lundi </th> 
        <th> Mardi </th> 
        <th> Merecredi </th> 
        <th> Jeudi </th> 
        <th> Vendredi </th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<?php

$counter_MS=0;
$counter_AI=0;
$counter_HA=0;
$last_shift = $input[2];

for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){

    echo "<td>\n";
    shuffle($input);

    // controle no one Continu working

    while ($input[0] == $last_shift) {
        shuffle($input);
    }

    // no one work 7 days a week
    while ($counter_MS == 6 && $input[0]="Mohamed ET Sidi" ||  $counter_MS == 6 && $input[1]="Mohamed ET Sidi"     || $counter_MS == 6 && $input[2]="Mohamed ET Sidi") {
        shuffle($input);
    }
    while ($counter_AI == 6 && $input[0]="Ahmed ET ibrahim" ||  $counter_MS == 6 && $input[1]="Ahmed ET ibrahim"     || $counter_MS == 6 && $input[2]="Ahmed ET ibrahim") {
        shuffle($input);
    }
     while ($counter_HA == 6 && $input[0]="Hamed Et abdou" ||  $counter_MS == 6 && $input[1]="Hamed Et abdou"     || $counter_MS == 6 && $input[2]="Hamed Et abdou") {
        shuffle($input);
    }


    if( $input[0] =="Mohamed ET Sidi" || $input[1]=="Mohamed ET Sidi" || $input[2]=="Mohamed ET Sidi")
        $counter_MS++;
    if( $input[0] =="Ahmed ET ibrahim" || $input[1]=="Ahmed ET ibrahim" || $input[2]=="Ahmed ET ibrahim")
        $counter_AI++;
    if( $input[0] =="Hamed Et abdou" || $input[1]=="Hamed Et abdou" || $input[2]=="Hamed Et abdou")
        $counter_HA++;

    echo  $input[0] ." 7H-15H\n" ;   
    echo  $input[1] ." 15H-23H\n" ;  
    echo  $input[2] ." 23H-7H\n" ;        

    $last_shift = $input[2];

    echo "</td>\n";
}
echo "Mohamed Et Sidi Worked =".$counter_MS." days";
echo "Ahmed ET ibrahim =".$counter_AI." days";
echo "Hamed Et abdou =".$counter_HA." days";
?>
```

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: Make person work 6days per week

Comment: ´Thats a statement, not a question :P

Comment: hhhh Ok add "how" before it

Comment: still not a correct question

Comment: clearify your question at the top or bottom of your question

Comment: how to be sure that every groupe work 6 days per week

Answer (score 1):

use this approach [image]ABCD are 4 people so you can use this approach and build an algorithm

Comment: @mohamedmed if you want all of them to do same amount of work , I don't think that's possible

Comment: I think it possible if we change personne  if they 6 or 8 what about that

Comment: sorry the photo is upside down , gimme a minute

Comment: done , accept the answer if it helped you , @mohamedmed

Comment: THat helped but didn't give me what I want the problem in Your Algorithm that u made 4 shift per day and we have just 3 shift ...don't care about people amount just tell me how much people needed to cover 21 shift per week and every one get one day free